# Automatically update record using if else in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I am new to MySql and need help.

To make it clearer, I have 3 columns in my MySql table;

1. Date of Membership
2. Membership Expiry
3. Membership Status

1st and 2nd column is using DATE format. And 3rd column using VARCHAR.

So, what I'm trying to do is, if the expiry date exceed current date, the record of the 3rd column automatically changed to 'EXPIRED'. And if it does not exceed, it will display 'ACTIVE'.

Is it possible?

Really appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports `EVENTS`. This is helpful when you do not want to manually check for the status of each record.

Example Code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `update_status`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR 
DO BEGIN
    UPDATE tableName
    SET MembershipStatus = IF(CURDATE() > MembershipExpiry, 'Expired', 'Active');
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

what the statement does is after the script has been created, it will be fired every `1 Hour` as its interval.

To lean more about `EVENTS`, please see the links below.

- [CREATE EVENT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)
- [More Examples](http://www.examplesof.com/mysql/create_event.html)